# Weibel exercise 1.1.2. the $n$th homology module is a functor from category Ch-Mod$(R)$ to Mod-$R$

Tags: modules, homological-algebra

**Ch-Mod$(R)$** is the category of $R$-module chain complexes.  How do you turn a homology module into a functor?

Thanks for teaching.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I've added question

Comment: For each complex $C_\cdot$ you have defined $H_n(C_\cdot)$; and for every chain map $f_\cdot:C_\cdot \to D_\cdot$ you have defined a morphism of modules $H_n(f_\cdot): H_n(C_\cdot)\to H_n(D_\cdot)$. What you want to do is check $H_n$ defined in this way a functor ${\bf Ch}({}_R {\rm mod})\to {}_R{\rm mod}$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff thanks.  That makes much more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pedro Tamaroff in a comment above.

I want to show that $H_n(\text{id}_{C}) = \text{id}_{H_n(C)}$.

$H_n(\text{id}_C) : H_n(C) \to H_n(C)$ is identity.

$H_n(f\circ g) = H_n(f) \circ H_n(g)$.  *Proof.* Let $g_n' =  H_n(g) : H_n(A) \to H_n(B) : z + B_n  \to g_n(z) + B_n$.  Clearly  $f_n'\circ g_n' = H_n(f_n \circ g_n)$.  Done